# How To Add Item To post-new.php and Edit.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to add html select to post-new.php and Edit.php in wordpress, so i made php-file.php and include it into theme function.php

but html select always shows top of page

how i can set it under default items (under post title and post description) ?

```
// ============================== Add Province And City ...
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'selectIranProvinceCity' );
// add_action( 'update_post_meta', 'selectIranProvinceCity' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'iranProvinceCitySavePostData' );
function selectIranProvinceCity(){

    // Load Province And City
    require_once( 'iran_province_city.php' );

}
function iranProvinceCitySavePostData($post_id){
    // Save Province And City
    $province = '';
    $city = '';
    // $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if( isset( $_POST['state'] ) ) {
        $province = $_POST['state'];
        if( !add_post_meta($post_id, 'job_province', $province, true ) ) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'job_province', $province );
        }
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['city'] ) ) {
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        if( !add_post_meta($post_id, 'job_city', $city, true ) ) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'job_city', $city );
        }
    }

}
// ============================== Add Province And City .
```

Answer (score 0):

use plugin for add combobox.
use Advanced custom fileds plugin.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to complement it with context, detailed information and/or code examples. The _Post Answer_ button should be used only for **complete answers to the question**.